# Dropdown only displaying the first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, code.org

I’ve been trying to create an app that displays information from a dataset. The problem is it only displays the data for the first option not the option the user selected. Can someone please help me

I tried changing creating a variable for the dropdown and then adding another first option. I also tried creating an array that holds the information for the option the user chose. They didn’t work

Comment: Please include some code so we can see what you’ve tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.